# LINQ to XML with subsets

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML dataset that contains multiple records and each record can contain 1 to many sub element with the same identifier group (see E04 elements in file)

```
<Record>
<E01>
<E01_01>9-542</E01_01>
<E01_02>Ortivus</E01_02>
<E01_03>Sweet-Billing &amp; Field Data</E01_03>
<E01_04>5.6.020120130</E01_04>
</E01>
<E02>
<E02_01>123</E02_01>
<E02_02>-20</E02_02>
<E02_03>F12006149</E02_03>
<E02_04>30</E02_04>
<E02_05>75</E02_05>
<E02_06>105</E02_06>
<E02_07>150</E02_07>
<E02_08>225</E02_08>
<E02_09>290</E02_09>
<E02_10>360</E02_10>
<E02_11>-20</E02_11>
<E02_12>447</E02_12>
<E02_13>-20</E02_13>
<E02_14>-20</E02_14>
<E02_17>2.3</E02_17>
<E02_18>3</E02_18>
<E02_19>3.7</E02_19>
</E02>
<E03>
<E03_01>445</E03_01>
<E03_02>-20</E03_02>
<E03_03>-25</E03_03>
</E03>
<E04>
<E04_01>155306</E04_01>
<E04_02>580</E04_02>
<E04_03>6120</E04_03>
</E04>
<E04>
<E04_01>032519</E04_01>
<E04_02>585</E04_02>
<E04_03>6090</E04_03>
</E04>
<E04>
<E04_01>083589</E04_01>
<E04_02>590</E04_02>
<E04_03>6090</E04_03>
</E04>
</Record>
```

My extract VB.NET code is like this (look for IncidentCrew below)

```
Dim ns As XNamespace = doc.Root.Name.[Namespace]            Tripsheets = _
           (From record In doc.Descendants(ns + "Record") _
                   Select New TripSheet() With _
                       { _
                        .PatientCareNumber = record.Descendants(ns + "E01_01").FirstOrDefault, _
                         .IncidentCrew = (From E0401 In doc.Descendants(ns + "E04") _
                              Select New Crew() With _
                                 { _
                                     .CrewID = cr.Descendants(ns + "E04_01").FirstOrDefault _
                                 }).ToArray, _
                        .MileageOut = record.Descendants(ns + "E02_16").FirstOrDefault, _
                        .MileageAtScene = record.Descendants(ns + "E02_17").FirstOrDefault, _
                        .MileageAtDestination = record.Descendants(ns+"E02_18").FirstOrDefault, _
                        .MileageInQuarters = record.Descendants(ns + "E02_19").FirstOrDefault, _
                            }).ToList
```

My problem here is that this code reads every E04_01 value from the XML file into the array named IncidentCrew.  If there are 200 records, then I get all E01_01 entries for all 200 records in each of the class named IncidentCrew.   I only want the values associated with one PatientCareNumber E01_01 which is unique in each Record read into the class named IncidentCrew which is defined as part of the TripSheet class.   The classes are shown below

```
Public Class TripSheet
    Public PatientCareNumber As String

    Public TimeDispatched As String
    Public TimeEnroute As String
    Public TimeAtScene As String
    Public TimeDepartScene As String
    Public TimeArriveFacility As String
    Public TimeAvailable As String
    Public TimeInQuarters As String

    Public MileageOut As String
    Public MileageAtScene As String
    Public MileageAtDestination As String
    Public MileageInQuarters As String
    Public IncidentCrew As Crew()
End Class
Public Class Crew
    Public CrewID As String
End Class
```

Can someone help me out here.   I am quite new to LINQ and I cannot see what is wrong or missing from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, quite a lot to cover. Firstly your subject tag for this question was "Linq-to-sql", not "linq-to-xml" so I've corrected that.

Second issue - is the XML format under your control? If so then you may want to consider rewriting it so the structure of the data matches the structure of your classes. This means you can serialize the XML directly into your classes. It makes it easier to read. For example your XML might be more readable if it looked like this:

```
Dim better = <TripSheet>
                         <PatientCareNumber>9-542</PatientCareNumber>
                         <!-- other fields -->
                         <MileageOut>123</MileageOut>
                         <MileageAtScene>321</MileageAtScene>
                         <MileageAtDestination>456</MileageAtDestination>
                         <IncidentCrew>
                             <Crew CrewID="1234"/>
                             <Crew CrewID="5678"/>
                             <Crew CrewID="9876"/>
                         </IncidentCrew>
                     </TripSheet>
```

I will assume this format has been imposed on you and you are not able to change it. In that case the key problem here is .Descendants() - this tells LINQ to XML to go down all the XML nodes and find ANY descendants with the name you gave that exists below the node called. You call this on the Record node so it finds them all.

I'd recommend [Mike Taulty's excellent talk](http://vimeo.com/1382705) on LINQ to XML

Instead you need to use .Element() or .Elements() which only looks at the first level. I've corrected the code here:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim xml = <Record>
                  <E01>
                      <E01_01>9-542</E01_01>
                      <E01_02>Ortivus</E01_02>
                      <E01_03>Sweet-Billing &amp; Field Data</E01_03>
                      <E01_04>5.6.020120130</E01_04>
                  </E01>
                  <E02>
                      <E02_01>123</E02_01>
                      <E02_02>-20</E02_02>
                      <E02_03>F12006149</E02_03>
                      <E02_04>30</E02_04>
                      <E02_05>75</E02_05>
                      <E02_06>105</E02_06>
                      <E02_07>150</E02_07>
                      <E02_08>225</E02_08>
                      <E02_09>290</E02_09>
                      <E02_10>360</E02_10>
                      <E02_11>-20</E02_11>
                      <E02_12>447</E02_12>
                      <E02_13>-20</E02_13>
                      <E02_14>-20</E02_14>
                      <E02_17>2.3</E02_17>
                      <E02_18>3</E02_18>
                      <E02_19>3.7</E02_19>
                  </E02>
                  <E03>
                      <E03_01>445</E03_01>
                      <E03_02>-20</E03_02>
                      <E03_03>-25</E03_03>
                  </E03>
                  <E04>
                      <E04_01>155306</E04_01>
                      <E04_02>580</E04_02>
                      <E04_03>6120</E04_03>
                  </E04>
                  <E04>
                      <E04_01>032519</E04_01>
                      <E04_02>585</E04_02>
                      <E04_03>6090</E04_03>
                  </E04>
                  <E04>
                      <E04_01>083589</E04_01>
                      <E04_02>590</E04_02>
                      <E04_03>6090</E04_03>
                  </E04>
              </Record>

    Dim doc As New XDocument(xml)

    'Dim ns As XNamespace = doc.Root.Name.[Namespace]

    'get each record

    Dim TripSheets = (From record In doc.Elements("Record") _
                     Let e01 = record.Element("E01") _
                     Let e02 = record.Element("E02") _
                     Let e04s = record.Elements("E04") _
                     Select New TripSheet With _
                            { _
                                .PatientCareNumber = e01.Element("E01_01"), _
                                .IncidentCrew = (From e04 In e04s _
                                                 Select New Crew() With {.CrewID = e04.Element("E04_01")}).ToArray(), _
                                .MileageOut = e02.Element("E02_16"), _
                                .MileageAtScene = e02.Element("E02_17"), _
                                .MileageAtDestination = e02.Element("E02_18"), _
                                .MileageInQuarters = e02.Element("E02_19") _
                            }).ToList()


    For Each trip In TripSheets
        Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1} crew", trip.PatientCareNumber, trip.IncidentCrew.Count)
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```